# Determining the Chromatic Index of a Graph

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I am attempting to find the chromatic index of the graph provided below. its chromatic index is either $4$ or $5$. I strongly believe that it is not $4$ but I currently lack a compelling method to demonstrate this.

[image]

Comment: It's not too hard to color the vertices with four colors.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I'm talking about an edge coloring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a four-edge coloring. Hope this helps

[image]